# Create XML document using C# with SQL Server as datasource

Tags: c#, xml, feed

I need to create an xml feed from my SQL Server database

I have seen it done in many different ways like: http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article67.aspx

However that seems to be just wrong..

What is the best an easiest way to go about this??

I have a XSD document to work from BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I find that LINQ to SQL + LINQ to XML works really nicely, so long as the result is small enough to fit in memory comfortably (i.e. it's not as good for a streaming solution).

For instance, I have a single (very large) statement which converts items in my database into an RSS feed. It's basically a declarative approach, and it works well. It's something like this:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
    new XElement("rss",
        new XAttribute("version", "2.0"),
        new XElement("channel",

            new { title="C# in Depth news",
                  link ="http://csharpindepth.com/News.aspx",
                  description = "C# in Depth news items",
                  language = "en-gb",
                  generator = "LINQ",
                  docs = "http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss",
                  pubDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString
                      (Rfc822Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                  lastBuiltDate = items.First().CreatedDate.ToString
                      (Rfc822Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            }.AsXElements(),
            items.Select(item =>
                new XElement("item",
                    new { title=item.Title, 
                          link=string.Format(LinkFormat, item.NewsItemID), 
                          description=item.Summary,
                          author="skeet@pobox.com",
                          pubDate = item.CreatedDate.ToString
                              (Rfc822Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    }.AsXElements()
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

That uses a little extension method I've got to convert anonymous types into XElements - it's available in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil), and does the obvious thing.

(And yes, I should probably have a method to convert dates to Rfc822 format...)

Answer (score 0):

For creating rss feeds i prefer http://www.rssdotnet.com/ , there classes work really well and since you are working with objects it makes generating your output quite easy if you have a DAL of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

You could always output XML from the database directly and then manipulate accordingly to add the correct root node and attributes. This is very straightforward in SQL Server 2005 onwards.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597941/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-xml-from-the-data-in-the-database/597987#597987) provides some detail on some of the options that you have.